# Symfony - redirect 404 to a custom template only from one URL

Tags: php, symfony

I have video rooms (via Twig) being created on my page when the users want to start a video chat between each other. When they leave the room, the room is being deleted after a period of time and they have to create a new room in order to start talking again. The problem is that I have a notification system that leaves the old URL in your notifications and when user tries to click that again after some period of time he receives a 404.

I don't want any superb solution at this point, I just want to move the user to custom twig template if the room is no longer available - let's say. 404video.html

Thanks for any help!

```
/**
 * @Route("/video/join/{room_name}", name="videochat_join")
 *
 * @param $room_name
 *
 * @return RedirectResponse|Response
 *
 * @throws \Twilio\Exceptions\ConfigurationException
 * @throws \Twilio\Exceptions\TwilioException
 */
public function joinVideo($room_name)
{
    $user = $this->getCurrentUser();
    $twilio = new Client(getenv('TWILIO_API_KEY'), getenv('TWILIO_API_SECRET'));
    $room = $twilio->video->v1->rooms($room_name)->fetch();
    $roomSid = $room->sid;
    $token = new AccessToken(getenv('TWILIO_ACCOUNT_SID'), getenv('TWILIO_API_KEY'), getenv('TWILIO_API_SECRET'), 3600, $user->getEmail());
    $videoGrant = new VideoGrant();
    $videoGrant->setRoom($room_name);
    $token->addGrant($videoGrant);
    return $this->render('chat/video_join.html.twig', [
        'roomSid' => $roomSid,
        'roomName' => $room_name,
        'accessToken' => $token->toJWT(),
    ]);
}
```

Comment: Please do not vandalise your post. This may result in a [question ban](http://stackoverflow.com/help/question-bans). By posting on the Stack Exchange network, you've granted a non-revocable right for SE to distribute that content (under the [CC BY-SA 3.0 license](https://creativecommons.org/licenses/by-sa/3.0/)).  By SE policy, any vandalism will be reverted. If you would like to disassociate this post from your account, see [What is the proper route for a disassociation request?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/323395)

Comment: Let's say it was a number of missclicks. ;)

Comment: I literally did have a cat run across my keyboard while in an online work chat. It does happen

Answer (score 1):

If you are using the Symfony 4 then you need to create template error404.html.twig in `templates/bundles/TwigBundle/Exception/`, So 404 page will render content from this error404.html.twig (custom template).

You can find more details on symfony official site: https://symfony.com/doc/current/controller/error_pages.html

Please note that the custom error page available only in production mode, so if you want to check custom 404 then you must have to run your application in production mode.

Comment: That's a little bit different unfortunately because it is Twig that is making an exception based on what it receives from the API, it's not a typical 404. In this case I wanted to close it within the code I have shared and forward to a customized 404x.html.twig template OR forward all exceptions from chat/video_join.html.twig (let's say) to a customized 404x.html.twig