# Fetch exception

Tags: php, symfony, twilio

I have video rooms (via Twig) being created on my page when the users want to start a video chat between each other. When they leave the room, the room is being deleted after a period of time so when I try to access it, it drops an error ({room_id} does not exist}. Below is the function:

```
/**
 * @Route("/video/join/{room_name}", name="videochat_join")
 *
 * @param $room_name
 *
 * @return RedirectResponse|Response
 *
 * @throws \Twilio\Exceptions\ConfigurationException
 * @throws \Twilio\Exceptions\TwilioException
 */
public function joinVideo($room_name)
{
    $user = $this->getCurrentUser();
    $twilio = new Client(getenv('TWILIO_API_KEY'), getenv('TWILIO_API_SECRET'));
    $room = $twilio->video->v1->rooms($room_name)->fetch();
    $roomSid = $room->sid;
    $token = new AccessToken(getenv('TWILIO_ACCOUNT_SID'), getenv('TWILIO_API_KEY'), getenv('TWILIO_API_SECRET'), 3600, $user->getEmail());
    $videoGrant = new VideoGrant();
    $videoGrant->setRoom($room_name);
    $token->addGrant($videoGrant);
    return $this->render('chat/video_join.html.twig', [
        'roomSid' => $roomSid,
        'roomName' => $room_name,
        'accessToken' => $token->toJWT(),
    ]);
};
```

How can I catch if the room is no longer available and forward user to 404_room.html.twig? Because it doesn't redirect to the default 404 template.

The error is:

```
RestException
Twilio\Exceptions\RestException:
[HTTP 404] Unable to fetch record: The requested resource /Rooms/1_2room808823 was not found

  at vendor/twilio/sdk/Twilio/Version.php:85
  at Twilio\Version->exception(object(Response), 'Unable to fetch record')
     (vendor/twilio/sdk/Twilio/Version.php:109)
  at Twilio\Version->fetch('GET', '/Rooms/1_2room808823', array())
     (vendor/twilio/sdk/Twilio/Rest/Video/V1/RoomContext.php:58)
  at Twilio\Rest\Video\V1\RoomContext->fetch()
     (src/Controller/Chat/VideoController.php:93)
  at App\Controller\Chat\VideoController->joinVideo('1_2room808823')
     (vendor/symfony/http-kernel/HttpKernel.php:149)
  at Symfony\Component\HttpKernel\HttpKernel->handleRaw(object(Request), 1)
     (vendor/symfony/http-kernel/HttpKernel.php:66)
  at Symfony\Component\HttpKernel\HttpKernel->handle(object(Request), 1, true)
     (vendor/symfony/http-kernel/Kernel.php:188)
  at Symfony\Component\HttpKernel\Kernel->handle(object(Request))
     (public/index.php:37)
```

I have tried to do:

```
    try{
        ($twilio->video->v1->rooms($room_name)->fetch());
        echo "Room exists"; //this one is working fine
}   catch ( TwilioException $e ) {
        echo 'Caught exception: ',  $e->getMessage(), "\n"; //this doesn't
}
```

...without luck

Comment: What is the content of `$room` if it's deleted? I would start from here.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Symfony - redirect 404 to a custom template only from one URL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52750944/symfony-redirect-404-to-a-custom-template-only-from-one-url)

Comment: @FelippeDuarte there is none, it's automatically being deleted on Twig's site after 5 minutes of inactivity.

Comment: What's the fully qualified class name for the exception being thrown?

Comment: So, check if it's empty. If empty, redirect to 404, else proceed normally.

Comment: I'll edit a post

Comment: It looks like you were really close. The only part you were missing was the need to throw the `NotFoundHttpException` to invoke the 404 response.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add the following `use` statements to the top of your `Controller` class.

```
use Symfony\Component\HttpKernel\Exception\NotFoundHttpException;
use Twilio\Exceptions\RestException;
```

Then wrap your code in a `try`/`catch` block. If you catch the expected `RestException`, then you can throw a `NotFoundHttpException` to force the 404 response. For example:

```
/**
* @Route("/video/join/{room_name}", name="videochat_join")
*
* @param  $room_name
*
* @return RedirectResponse|Response
*
* @throws \Twilio\Exceptions\ConfigurationException
* @throws \Twilio\Exceptions\TwilioException
*/
public function joinVideo($room_name)
{
    try {
        $user = $this->getCurrentUser();

        $twilio = new Client(getenv('TWILIO_API_KEY'), getenv('TWILIO_API_SECRET'));
        $room = $twilio->video->v1->rooms($room_name)->fetch();
        $roomSid = $room->sid;

        $token = new AccessToken(getenv('TWILIO_ACCOUNT_SID'), getenv('TWILIO_API_KEY'), getenv('TWILIO_API_SECRET'), 3600, $user->getEmail());
        $videoGrant = new VideoGrant();
        $videoGrant->setRoom($room_name);
        $token->addGrant($videoGrant);

        return $this->render('chat/video_join.html.twig', [
            'roomSid' => $roomSid,
            'roomName' => $room_name,
            'accessToken' => $token->toJWT(),
        ]);
    }
    catch (RestException $exception) {
        throw new NotFoundHttpException("'{$room_name}' could not be found");
    }
}
```

Comment: Fubar you are a life saver, thanks a lot. The semicolon at the end is not necessary though.